# glassfish 4 programmatic login

Tags: authentication, glassfish

In glassfish 3.1.2 the ProgrammaticLogin class was in `glassfish/modules/security.jar`. But in glassfish 4.0 it seems that it doesn't exist anymore. Does anybody know what happened to the ProgrammaticLogin class?

When I use the ProgrammaticLogin class from 3.1.2 with glassfish 4, I get a `NoSuchMethodError` for `SecurityServicesUtil.getHabitat()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class was moved and can be found in

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\modules\security-ee.jar
```

It is in package `com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know on which other jars security-ee.jar depends? I added security.jar and glassfish-api.jar, but there is still an exception during deployment (i.e.  Annotation `RestEndpoints` is not a qualifier)

Comment: I'm not sure but the RestEndpoints class is in glassfish-api.jar.

Comment: I added glassfish-api.jar, but still the same exception. Thanks anyway