# Access glassfish security realm from within the application

Tags: security, java-ee-6, glassfish-4.1

I am using a glassfish 4.1 application server for a web application. The web application authentication/authorization is done by a glassfish ldap realm. So I do not have to implement and configure the ldap connection within my application but within the glassfish container. That's good!

Now I need to implement a login method with username/password in my application (WebService). The parameters are passed within a SOAP request. 
I want to access another configured ldap realm from the glassfish and pass the username/password to it. As a result I want to know whether the user is authorized.

Is it somehow possible to access a security realm of the application server from within the application and perform a login request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to access the realm directly, but in Glassfish there is the (non-portable) programmatic authentication via `com.sun.appserv.security.ProgrammaticLogin` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacm.html). For Glassfish 4 see also [glassfish 4 programmatic login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571932/glassfish-4-programmatic-login).